# cascade shadow alternative solution since it's removed from three.js?

Tags: three.js

i have a large scene, and the directionlight is far from the ground, so the objects's shadows are very weak and ugly...
since the CSM is removed from three.js, so what is the alternative solution to improve shadow for a large scene?

Answer (score 0):

More recently, a newer Cascaded Shadow Map implementation: https://github.com/vtHawk/three-csm